# wait for a single element from a list of elements to be clickable, in selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

let's say I have the following line of code:

```
inner_elems_list = outer_elem.find_elements_by_name('name_of_elem')
```

this line works perfectly, and returns a list of 2 elements.
I want to click the second one:

```
inner_elems_list[1].click()
```

before that, I want to make sure it is clickable and if not wait for it to be. I am aware of this option:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "name"))
```

but this will not do - it checks a single item that has a unique name, but I have a list of 2, and I don't know how to get this function to work on the second one.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a web element directly as a parameter to expected conditions. Like this

```
inner_elems_list = outer_elem.find_elements_by_name('name_of_elem')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(inner_elems_list[1])
```

Comment: won't I get error "find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement " since the "element_to_be_clickable" expects a locator, not a webelement?

Comment: AFAIK this should work. Please try and let me know. I use Java, there we have much rich variability of expected conditions, also receiving web elements and locators as parameters for each kind of expected conditions

Comment: Have you tried this or will be able only on Sunday at work?

Comment: That does not work, I get error: "find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement"

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you've wrote here

Comment: there is nothing much to understand, I just stated that is does not work and gave the error

Comment: What code line gives this error? Also, it can be helpful if you share your actual code, not just 1 line from there.

Comment: the second line of your code gives the error.

Comment: Are you sure you copied my code correct? `find_elements_by_name` returns a list of web elements. So `inner_elems_list` should be a list, iterable.

Comment: it is a list, until you put "[1]" at the end, thus extracting a single element from the list - which is no longer a list